# Deploying cloned elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have one elastic beanstalk deployment that is up and running. I cloned that environment successfully however, I cannot figure out how to deploy new environment by using same codebase.

Is there an easy work around to deploy new cloned environments in eb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to the elastic-beanstalk service in the AWS console you can go to the `Application Version`. 
Select the latest version of your application and choose `deploy` on the upper right bar. And then you can choose your newly created environment.

From (AWS) EB CLI you can simply use `eb deploy [env-name]`.

Comment: "... AWS CLI you can simply use eb deploy [env-name]". You mean, from the EB CLI.